# What is the use of Error, throws and catch?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get my head around the use of errors in swift for example I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum SomeError: Error
    {
        case badWord
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        do {
            try checkWord()
        }
        catch SomeError.badWord {
            print("error!")
        }
        catch { //This is like a defualt statement
            print("Something weird happened")
        }

    }

    func checkWord() throws {
        let word = "crap"
        guard word != "crap" else {
            throw SomeError.badWord
        }
        print("Continuing the function")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The `checkWord` function will terminate if the word is bad. However the same behaviour can be achieved with:

```
func checkWord() {
  let word = "crap"
  guard word != "crap" else {
    print("error!")
    return

   }
   print("Continuing the function")
 }
```

So what is the use of defining the errors and going through the catch statements?

Comment: The benefit is at the site where you call the function. The `JSONSerialization` library is a good example. If you pass data that is not valid JSON, it will throw an error. In Objective-C, you would pass an error pointer to the method, then check it for an error afterwards. In Swift, the method either returns the correct result, or throws an error on failure.

Comment: You're also presuming that `checkWord` might fail for only one reason. Often, you might have a variety of reasons that an error might have been thrown, and, as Martin said, the calling routine may want to take different action based upon the type of error. See The [Swift Programming Language: Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) for richer example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 2nd implementation of `checkWord`, the caller of `checkWord` has no way to know the result of the check.

The whole idea of throwing errors and then catching them is that you can cleanly define responsibility for handling errors.

For example, your `checkWord` function's job is to check for bad words. But it should not make any assumptions about what should be done when a bad word is found. `checkWord` might be called from many different places, even by different apps (if you made it available in a framework, for example). So your `checkWord` function should do its check and throw an error if appropriate. Let the caller of `checkWord` decide how best to handle the error. It might decide to show a message to the user. It might decide to simply log it and move on. The point is, `checkWord` shouldn't care. Let the caller decide what's best.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It allows other functions in your code to define how the error is handled and it's not limited to the implementation within its  method. I guess this is also useful for writing frameworks where the user can't edit the source but you still want to give them the option of how the error is handled.